# When was the STRLEN opcode introduced in PHP?

Tags: php, opcode, language-history

I was surprised while checking the opcodes generated by a PHP script, that unlike other string functions like `str_pad()`, `strlen()` is not a function call like it used to (if I'm not mistaken), but has a dedicated `STRLEN` opcode:

```php
strlen($c);
str_pad($c, 2);
```

```
...

   8     4        STRLEN                                           ~7      !2

...

   9     6        INIT_FCALL                                               'str_pad'
         7        SEND_VAR                                                 !2
         8        SEND_VAL                                                 2
         9        DO_ICALL
```

https://3v4l.org/9QJQ7/vld#output

**In which PHP version was this opcode introduced?** I couldn't find this information anywhere.

Comment: Close vote: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"... No comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The STRLEN opcode was added in PHP 7.0. [Here's the commit that introduced it.](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/6c8db864e047271fed082562a183e141b40c130e)

There are a number of other functions which have dedicated opcodes; currently, these functions are:

- Certain type-checking functions (`is_null`, `is_bool`, `is_long`, `is_int`, `is_integer`, `is_float`, `is_double`, `is_real`, `is_string`, `is_array`, `is_object`, `is_resource`)
- Certain type-casting functions (`intval`, `floatval`, `doubleval`, `strval`)
- `defined`
- `chr` and `ord`
- `call_user_func` and `call_user_func_array`
- `in_array`
- `count` (aka `sizeof`)
- `get_class`
- `get_called_class`
- `gettype`
- `func_get_args` and `func_num_args`
- `array_slice`
- `array_key_exists`

Comment: Thank you! Have most of the other opcodes you mention been introduced in PHP 7.0 as well?

Comment: There's a few too many for me to go through and check them all, but most signs point to `strlen` having been the first function to get this treatment. Many of the other functions I listed were specialized in later major releases.

Comment: Sorry, I meant PHP 7.x. So I assume most of these, if not all of these, have been introduced in PHP 7!

Comment: All of the ones I mentioned, yes. A couple of functions with special runtime behaviors (like `unset` and `exit`) have always had their own opcodes.